# How to get out dir of my project in Azure DevOps build pipeline?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, csproj

I build the solution using

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

I need to get build output of a `/tests/IntergationTests/IntegrationTests.csproj` (non-web project) and publish build artifacts:

```yaml
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish integration tests artifacts'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: ??
    artifactName: 'IntegrationTests'
```

**How to get the output path of specific project?**

Is there anything better than hardcoded `/tests/IntergationTests/bin/$(buildConfiguration)/net5`? It can easily change, e.g. when changing target framework.

Comment: Well, you _could_ specify the "PublishDir" for both steps explicitly (`arguments: '-p:PublishDir=<whatever> ...'` and `pathtoPublish: <whatever>`). That way, at least it is explicit in either case. There might be better ways though...

Comment: What is `-p:PublishDir={...}`? I have tried to invoke `dotnet build -p:PublishDir=whatever`, but the parameter does nothing. On the other side `dotnet build -o whatever` flattens all projects into single folder which is not good

Comment: `-p:<Prop>=<Value>` passes the property `<Prop>` with `<Value>` on to msbuild, much like when you would invoke `Msbuild.exe /p:<Prop>=<Value>` directly. `PublishDir` is the msbuild property that controls where the output of `dotnet publish` goes to. It has no effect on `dotnet build` - so this might be the issue. I think I have gotten you backwards. Sorry. Can't you just have one pipeline step (`dotnet publish`) and be done with it?

Comment: `dotnet publish /tests/IntergationTests/IntegrationTests.csproj --output whatever` solves the issue and that is what I'm actually doing. However, tests projects are not web projects and are not supposed to be published, so I'm looking for alternative solution

Comment: @Liero other question: does something prevent you from using the CLI to test the project (`dotnet test integrationtests.csproj --no-build -c `$(buildConfiguration) equivalent)?

Comment: (as a side note: the test sdk nuget package actually makes your project publishable, even adds an empty Main() method during the build..; the test host needs the generated runtimeconfig.json to correctly launch the target test process for specific .NET 3/5/6/* runtimes)

Comment: Build is part of build pipeline, integration tests part of deployment pipeline and they require the app to be deployed first. I would be weird to build the sources in deployment pipeline again.